# Unauthorized action because POST parameter is null

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have the following code:

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('blog', PostController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

**PostController.php**

```
public function edit(Post $post): View
{
    $this->authorize('update', $post);
 
    return view('blog.edit', [
        'post' => $post,
    ]);
}
```

**PostPolicy.php**

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post): bool
{
    return $post->user()->is($user);
}
```

blog > **edit.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('blog.update', $post) }}">
```

When I try to access the post using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/1/edit
```

I get the `403 | THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.` page. If I comment out: `$this->authorize('update', $post);` I get the following error message:

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: blog.update] [URI: blog/{blog}] [Missing parameter: blog].
```

with reference to the `<form>` row. Could someone point me in the right direction, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use `method='GET'` for editing a resource.

Comment: There are two routes (edit & update ), the edit route should be like this `/photos/{photo}/edit` , and the update route is like this `/photos/{photo}` . for update route the method should be `PUT` not `POST`.

Comment: I think your problem is with structure of your action ... maby you wrote it as wrong or pass false data to it ...

Comment: Try adding `->parameter('blog', 'post')` to your `Route::resource(...)`

Comment: where are you passing blog as param to the post request, can you echo `$post` variable and share the output? Also what do you mean by `When I try to access the post using the following URL - http://localhost:8000/blog/1/edit`, is it valid post request? isn't it a get request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like:

```
Route::resource('blog', PostController::class)
    ->parameter('blog', 'post')
    ->only(['index', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```